# How can I get any programs to only/always interact with D: instead instead of C:?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, operating-systems, path, disk-space

I've built a rig with a small SSD for C: which I want to be pretty much only for the OS, and a HDD D: drive. Problem is, even when I tell them to install and run from D: a lot of programs keep sending stuff to C: anyway, which constantly fills it up. In short, can I somehow tell any program when it opens a folder "go here"?
Is there some sort of script I can write for it or setting I can tweak?

Unlike other questions, this is more about being proactive about installing new programs on a new machine rather than rebuilding an existing machine or moving files around.
I'm running Windows 10 (home).
EDIT: This question applies to things like globally installed software/plugins and databases as I'm a web developer. (To be specific, NPM and other Node.js dependencies for the former and MongoDB for the latter).

Comment: If you make `C:\Program Files`, `C:\Program Files (x86)`, `C:\ProgramData` and `C:\Users` into links pointing at corresponding directories on `D:`, then nearly all installed programs and data will go into `D:`. Some installers add files to the Windows directory, and these will of course go into `C:`.

Comment: Sounds about right for what I need. How do I do that properly?

Comment: -Ramhound
Unfortunately, some programs still install stuff into C:/Program Files even If I specify a D: drive location.

Comment: @DanielBraunstein yes, that is why Ramhoud posted a duplicate for mklink, which can be used to move the program files physically to the D drive, while placing a reference link on the C drive. Programs install to the C drive, but the reference link automatically redirects the files to the D drive. Opening C:\Program Files still shows your files, but they are actually stored on D.

Comment: Ramhoud basically answered your question to AFH, on how to do what AFH suggested.

Comment: @DanielBraunstein If you move ProgramFiles folder many programs may not work. I've an answer for your question. But the procedure depends on the software which you install. If you mention one or two software name I can write it in answer.

Answer (score -1):

You may have to copy and paste things like IE over to D: to prevent breakage.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion

- CommonFilesDir
- CommonFilesDir (x86)
- CommonW6432Dir
- ProgramFilesDir
- ProgramFilesDir (x86)
- ProgramW6432Dir

And of course you need to move common files and etc to the D: drive.
You will probably break already installed software, and may have to manually search and replace the registry to make everything point to C: now point to D:.  Re-installing might be faster.